# I am trying to get the date for the next 7 days

Tags: sql, date

Hello does anyone know how to solve this problem, I am trying to get the company, site, job title, closing date and number of applications made to date for vacancies with a closing date within the next seven days in sql. So far i have come up with this solution

```
Select company_name, location, job_title, closing_date 
from application 
where convert (datetime,date,101) between (getdate()+6) and getdat() 
order by date;
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  Date functions are database dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You should really store your data as the appropriate datatypes so that you don't have to `CONVERT` it every single time.

This should do what you want:

```
Select company_name, location, job_title, closing_date 
from application 
where convert (datetime, closing_date, 101) between Convert(Date, GetDate()) And Convert(Date, DateAdd(Day, 6, GetDate())) 
order by closing_date;
```

Comment: Worse, storing dates as strings means a query like this cannot use an index. It will have to do a full table scan.